# How to change the image of the button on click of the button in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have placed a pause button in UI, where when the user clicks the button, the image of button from pause image it has to change to the start image. I have placed both the start and the pause images in the bundle, I am able to do this,but when i click on start again , it should show pause image button,How to do this, the following is the code i am using,

```
-(IBAction)btnClked:(id)sender
{

    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;


    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable to keep track of that state change. A BOOL is fine.

But using your code, you can "abuse" the tag property of UIButton to tell if it's playing (tag == 1) or paused (tag == 0)

```
-(IBAction)btnClked:(id)sender {
     UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
     if (btn.tag == 1) {
         btn.tag = 0;
         [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     } else {
         btn.tag = 1;
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIButton's selected state to do the same. For example, while initiating the button you have to define 2 images. One for normal state and other for selected state. When touch event of the button fired, you have to make it selected. If it is already selected you need to deselect it. This is much better, than maintaining additional variables to check selected state of the button. Also you could improve the performance with this approach.

Code example

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *startButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 60, 60)];
    [startButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [startButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(modeButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:startButton];
}

- (IBAction)modeButtonClick:(id)sender {
    UIButton *startButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [startButton setSelected:![startButton isSelected]];
}
```

If you are creating the button from story board or XIBs set the backgroud image for default state config and selected state config.